# Linux BASH script to determine number of users logged in?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

i need help in writing BASH script that determines the number of potential users for the system by getting a count of the number of passwords contained in the system's password file.
    i tried /etc/passwd. It always comes up saying "Permission Denied".
     and also the script that determines the number of users currently logged in to the system.This script is to be run in an unattended batch manner without any input from the keyboard other than being invoked.

thank you.

Comment: On systems, that I have used, `/etc/passwd` has always been world-readable.  To determine whether the permission problem you see is with  `/etc/passwd` or not, please run `ls -l /etc/passwd` and report the result.

Comment: That file should be readable by all users. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

Comment: "permission denied" might simply mean that your script is not executable.  Try `chmod +x script-name`

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

You should use *who* to count logged-in users, and get a more complete count of normal users (as opposed to system accounts) by summing UIDs in the proper range from /etc/passwd.

### Counting Logins

On Linux, you can count active logins (which may include multiple logins by the same user) with the *who* command:

```
$ who --count
foo bar baz quux
# users=4
```

You can parse out the total from that last line any way you like. Some examples include:

```
# Using a Perl-compatible grep.
$ who --count | pcregrep -o 'users=\K.*'
4

# Counting unique logins when *who* doesn't have a --count flag.
$ who | sort --key=1,1 --unique | wc --lines
4
```

but there are too many ways to do it to make a truly canonical list. The main thing to note is that without sorting, you may be counting the same user more than once if that user is logged in on more than one TTY or PTY at a time.

### Count Non-System Accounts

#### Fix Filesystem Permissions

First, you need to fix the permissions on /etc/passwd. This file is generally set to mode 644 on distributions like Ubuntu that support shadow passwords. For exampe:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/passwd
```

If you don't have sudo access, then you'll have to speak to your systems administrator about changing the permissions of the file. If that's not permitted by your company's security policy, you can be granted sudo access to read the file with something like:

```
# Allow user "nadh" to print the contents of /etc/passwd as root.
nadh ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /etc/passwd
```

This level of sudo access is quite restrictive, as it only allows you to cat that one file; it won't even allow you pass flags or other arguments to cat.

Another alternative is to use extended attributes on the filesystem to grant access to a specific user or group, but that's generally a more complicated approach and isn't as portable.

#### Count UIDs

On Ubuntu, user accounts have UIDs in the range of 1000-65533 (65534 usually belongs to the *nobody* account). Once you're able to read /etc/passwd, you can count all the users in the allowable range. For example:

```
awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3<65534 {i+=1}; END {print i}' /etc/passwd
```

#### Count Home Directories

Counting UIDs obviously won't be accurate if you also have users defined through NIS, LDAP, or some other non-local lookup. As an alternative, you could count *local* home directories with:

```
ls /home | wc -l
```

for a reasonable approximation.

This may not be reliable if you store service account data in /home instead of /var or /srv, or if you are using NFS with auto-mounting. Your mileage will vary.

Comment: Kuddos for your answer @CodeGnome!
How does a simple `users | wc -l` differs from the longer `who | sort (options) | wc`? Is it for duplicate user sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this command, I think it will be helpful to determine number of users currently logged in,

```
$ who|wc -l
```

For discarding duplicate user sessions and count only unique users logged in currently in system.

```
$ users | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: This will also count duplicate user sessions.

Comment: `who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l` or, using just awk,   `who | awk '{if ($1 in seen);else count++; seen[$1]=1} END{print `count}'`